# Autohotkey variable expressions for pseudo-arrays - Convert String to Number?

Tags: arrays, variables, macros, autohotkey

**This question was answered at the bottom of this post.**

I have looked at 6 different web pages from the AHK forums asking this question, and another one on SO here:

[String to Number using autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958438/string-to-number-using-autohotkey)

...but none of them are working for me. I'm just trying to subtract a number from a string that has been grabbed from the StringSplit function. This is my code:

```
; Assign entry price variable. 
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n
MsgBox, Your entry price is %prices32%.

; Assign Stop Loss variable
SLPrice := %prices32% -= 0.10
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.
```

I receive the error "**The following variable name contains an illegal character**" on the line "**SLPrice := %prices32% -= 0.10**", so then I try:

```
; Assign entry price variable. 
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n
MsgBox, Your entry price is %prices32%.

; Assign Stop Loss variable
SLPrice = %prices32% - 0.10
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.
```

...to which I get the output:

```
Your SLPrice is 7.450 - 0.10
```

So it just displays the formula as a text string, it doesn't actually do the calculation.

Thoughts? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
To continue working out this solution, here is my full code up to the part I'm having an issue with, along with screenshots of what's happening:

```
; Get the latest window text to parse values from it
WinGetText, Window1Text, ahk_class WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.f96fc5_r9_ad1
MsgBox, The text is: %Window1Text% ; Displays the window get text values
Sleep, 5
```

[image: winGetText Results]

```
; Assign entry price variable.
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n
MsgBox, Your entry price is %prices32%.
```

[image: Entry Price MsgBox]

```
; Assign Stop Loss variable
SLPrice := prices32 - 0.10
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.
```

[image: Blank Stop Loss MsgBox]

**ANSWER**
Thanks to the contributor below, we discovered that there was a "." from the first MsgBox messing up the SLPrice variable, so we updated the SLPrice variable to read:

```
SLPrice := SubStr(Trim(prices32), 1, 5) - 0.10 ; to pull the left 5 characters
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does removing the `%` signs (`SLPrice = prices32 - 0.10`) make any difference?

Comment: it should, but not how you have it. It's `SLPrice := prices32 - 0.10` because the `:=` operator presumes expressions! See my answer for details.

Comment: @PGilm See my comment below. I think we're close, but now the second msgbox isn't actually displaying the number?

Comment: Yes, my original post had typos in the variable (since I changed it to suit a test case for myself). I then edited the answer (a few times) to clarify and when I noticed that mistake (I used `prices2`).  So I added an illustrative example after your comment.  Well, then I got interested in using it more generally with the pseudo array you created from `Window1Text` and added the version with an input box and the ***pseudo array variable expression*** because that's why there are pseudo arrays in AHK!

Comment: @PGilm I really appreciate your input, but something still isn't working on my end with your updated answers. I've updated my question above to include my complete code and with screenshots of what the MsgBox's show me. Your example works when you feed it the array the way you have, but when I try to update it to use my data from the SplitString, it doesn't work :( I'm running AHK 1.1.30.03. Any more thoughts? OR am I just missing something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: OK, I see the problem.  Your SplitString is also returning a non-printing character in the line 32.  So, try it like so: `SLPrice := Trim(prices32) - 0.10` to Trim the non-printing character. Else, start stripping off the right most character one at a time until you get a number. I edited below.

Comment: @PGilm Thanks, but it's still not displaying the SLPrice in the MsgBox :(

Comment: @PGilm I also tried using 3 functions at the bottom of this page too, but no go:

https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=10749

Comment: @MattWilson Well, from the first msgbox there is something causing the "." to wrap to the next line. Maybe use: `SLPrice := SubStr(Trim(prices32), 1, 5) - 0.10` to pull the left 5 characters?

Comment: @PGilm Bingo!! That did it! Thanks a lot! I'll update my question with this answer, and I'll mark your below answer as the one that fixed it. Thanks so much for your input, you taught me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  But, per my comment, note `:=` implies expressions including variable expressions (hence no surrounding `%`'s):

```
; Assign entry price variable. 
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n
MsgBox, Your entry price is %prices32%.

; Assign Stop Loss variable
; Note, the 32 line also includes non printing characters
; so must be trimmed and then we take the left 5 characters
SLPrice := SubStr(Trim(prices32), 1, 5) - 0.10
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.
```

Should do it . . .

And note, using `something := %myvariable%` implies reading the contents of a variable named `myvariable` and using those contents as the variable name.  So if `myvariable` is "test", you are really saying `something := test` (where something ends up being equal to the contents of the `test` variable).

Hth,

EDIT per below, here is a working example (BUT PER LATTER COMMENT, SEE BELOW, TOO):

```
Window1Text =
(
25
26
27
28
)

; Assign entry price variable. 
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n
MsgBox, Your entry price is %prices2%.  ;  using only 2nd line (26)

; Assign Stop Loss variable
SLPrice := prices2 - 0.10  ;  again, changed to 2nd line
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.  ;  25.900000
clipboard := SLPrice
```

HTH,

FURTHER EDIT: Because this is really cool and illustrates the several concepts as to how they relate to pseudo array variable expressions:

```
Window1Text =
(
25
26
27
28
)

; Assign entry price variable. 
StringSplit, prices, Window1Text, `n  ;  (prices0 is the number of entries)
InputBox, num,, % "Pick an array number from 1 to " prices0  ;  get the array number
; note the variable expression includes the num variable contents
MsgBox, % "Your entry price is " Trim(prices%num%) "."  ;  depends on array number

; Assign Stop Loss variable
SLPrice := Trim(prices%num%) - 0.10  ;  uses the array number value
MsgBox, Your SLPrice is %SLPrice%.  ;  so depends on the array number
clipboard := SLPrice
```

Right?

But note, these testers work easily. The real life example from the OP is copied text and the line 32 contains non-printing characters dealt with by `Trim(x)` and taking only the first few characters from Left with `SubStr(x,1,5)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Clear explanation, but I'm just curious, the second MsgBox is now displaying the text _Your SLPrice is ._ So the message box isn't displaying the integer? If that makes sense. I'd like it to tell me exactly what the SLPrice number is so that I know it's working (ie. it's taking 0.10 off of the entry price number, if that makes sense). I really appreciate your input!

Comment: Make sure you copy it completely. I had to make an edit because my original test didn't have a 32 line entry for `Window1Text` so I wrote it in my test as `prices2` and originally used that in my answer.  I'll add a test to show. Otherwise, what ver of AHK? Mine is up to date.

Comment: Or better yet, another working example that also illustrates the use of variable expressions in expressions (namely, the `something := %variable%` version).